# Isolate.spawnUri currently results in error when including SendPort within message?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Current Dart environment:
Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.69.0 (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"

I am attempting to spawn an isolate via the **Isolate**.*spawnUri* method, and include a **SendPort** within the message.  The code I have is set up like:

```
import 'dart:convert' show json;
import 'dart:isolate';

var servicePort = new ReceivePort()
  ..listen (/stuff to handle response/);

Map isolateRequest = {
  'sendPort': servicePort.sendPort,  <-- String => SendPort
  'info': json.encode (/info to send to spawned isolate/)  <-- String => String
};

Isolate.spawnUri (new Uri.file (/isolate main/), [], isolateRequest);
```

This type of set up used to work.  Now I get the following error:

> "Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a regular Dart Instance)"

The two keys for the Map are strings, and the values include a **SendPort** and another string.  Simple, nothing fancy, and should be acceptable to send as the message to spawn the isolate (worked perfectly up until a few days ago).

Questions:  what changed that I am now doing something wrong?  What are potential workarounds?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This does not reproduce for me with a freshly build VM from the 2.0.0-dev.69.0 tag (--version is: Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.69.0 (Tue Jul 17 14:57:16 2018 +0200) on "linux_x64").

Using this complete program:

```
import 'dart:convert' show json;                                                    
import 'dart:isolate';
main(args, message) {
  if (message != null) {
    print("Out, ");
    message["sendPort"].send("And home again!");
    return;
  }
  var servicePort = new ReceivePort();
  servicePort.forEach((m) {  
    print(m);
    servicePort.close();
  });
  Map isolateRequest = {
    'sendPort': servicePort.sendPort, //  <-- String => SendPort
    'info': json.encode({})  // <-- String => String
  };
  Isolate.spawnUri (new Uri(path:"iso.dart"), [], isolateRequest);
}
```

it runs and prints the expected lines. 
The isolate request does look like something that should be serializable (map with string keys and values that are either strings or a `SendPort`), something *else* must be going on in the code you are not showing.

Can you extract a runnable program from your code which still exhibits this behavior, or say something more about what happens around the code?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  After several days of experimenting, it turned out the issue was in sending a response message back from the spawned isolate.  Something changed with the past few dev releases, and now it seems the isolate does not like sending a map that contains another map as a value.  I have more experimenting to do...

Comment: Did you you have any luck troubleshooting your case? I now have similar troubleshooting with spawned isolate communicating back to main isolate, the main isolate seem to have a native crash when receiving a message